Can I use pH test papers with a dye-rich solution?
I'm working on some lactic acid fermentation of blueberries at home, and I'm trying to get a better handle on the process by logging the pH of the fermentation medium as the fermentation takes place.
I got the advice from a chemist that getting a digital pH meter wasn't worth the trouble, and so I'm starting with acid-range pH test papers similar to these from Sigma.
In my initial attempts to get a reading, I'm concerned that the strong blue-purple dyes being extracted from the blueberries are masking the result on the pH test strip.
With the disclaimer I'm very much not a chemist, is this something to be concerned about, or are the readings from the test strip going to work irrespective of what's dissolved in the solution?

In context of chemistry, as pigments are usually meant rather solid particles like ocre, moot, or white lead, while soluble colorful compound like anthocyans in plants are called dyes. The pigment can by partially filter out. // One of the way is one time measurent by pH if possible, and make note about the color. As these dyes change the color with pH.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/anthocyanins-as-ph-indicators-stop-the-titration-at-red-purple-or-blue

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/176009/anthoncyanins-and-its-maximum-absorbance-value

You have to visually test it yourself, how much the color of the solution affects evaluation of color strips. But as blueberry joice has intense color, I have my doubts.

There are very cheap handheld pH meters available (for <$30, example) about as or more accurate than indicator paper (which is accurate to ~0.5 pH units) and useful over a wide pH range (precision is typically a tenth of a pH unit, accuracy depends on the sample and calibration). One reason probes are useful is precisely to avoid interference when measuring in opaque or colored solutions.
A probe might have disadvantages. You should calibrate the probe. A buffer powder for preparation of a calibration solution may follow (you'll need distilled water). Proper immersion can require a larger volume than pH paper does. They can drift and be glitchy and have to be kept clean, but still, precision and accuracy will be as good or better.

I was working with dyes the other day, and happen to have come across this question. When working with natural dyes, if the dye is light coloured, then dipping a, pH strip would not be a problem. However, highly colored dye baths that are rich in iron or are a strong cochineal bath, would require you to simply dip the tip of the strip into the solution.(Might work sometimes, but cannot guarantee)
In the case of your blueberries, the strong blue-purple dyes might mask the the color change of the indicator on the strip. If so, you would have to consider investing in a digital pH probe. Regardless, if you don't want to go through the struggle of calibration and maintenance, then try reaching out to a lab or college near your place and request them for using their pH probe. Either ways, a pH probe will be more accurate in its readings and would be ideal for your case.

Search on line for pH meters there are some inexpensive hand held. Calibrate with 5% bicarbonate solution, look up the pH, and buy a small bottle of distilled white 5% vinegar, calculate the pH,to check slope and function. no need to buy buffer solutions to get consistent readings.
